# How to increase the size of a bucket in Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am currently working on model.derivative-WebAPI-sample. Where I can only store 10 items in a Bucket. How and where can I limit the size of a bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can upload more than 10 items in a bucket. I believe you just miss the parameter "**limit**" when you are querying the items in a bucket. By default, the API **GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects** only returns 10 items at most, but you can change the limit value to 100 at most, please check the "**Query String Parameters**" section at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/ for details.

Comment: Thanks ! It works now ... i just changed Getbuckets(id, int item)